# How do you print or echo the value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this prepared statement and the response I get is: Array ( [0] => John)
How can I just echo: John ?

```
  $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT nom,prenom FROM clients WHERE num_client = ?");
  $stmt1->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['User']);
  $stmt1->execute();
  $result = $stmt1->get_result();
  if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $prenom[] = $row['prenom'];
    // $nom[] = $row['nom'];
    //$ages[] = $row['age'];
  }
  var_export($prenom);
  print_r ($prenom);
  $stmt1->close();
```

Comment: `$prenom = $row['prenom'];` obviously. Or `print_r ($prenom[0]);`

Comment: `$prenom[0]` or stop packing data into the array

Comment: Thanks alot! Just started using prepared statements and I don't fully get it